# Ethernet button and Wifi button not showing in interface

Tags: wifi, kali-linux

I have installed kali linux in my old PC which is the only one in my pc. At first everything worked allright but now in the top bar when I click I just see Proxy and bluetooth options, internet is still working and the PC detects the ethernet cable and the USB wireless card.

Airmon also detects the wireless card but when i take the ethernet cable off i can not use the internet.

Any ideas to make these 2 buttons appear again and so I can connect via the USB wireless card?

Answer (score 1):

You might have changed the mode of your wireless card to monitor mode at some point. So what you need to do is stop the monitor mode.

`airmon-ng stop wlp2s0`

Here wlp2s0 is the name of wireless card . Replace it with yours. Then you can restart your network manager service. This might not be necessary.

`service network-manager restart`